# Lengthen an extremely large data frame with massive sparsity

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame such as this (but of size 16 Billion):

```
structure(list(id1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), id2 = c("a",
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), b1 = c(NA, NA,
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), b2 = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
1, 1, 1, 1), b3 = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1), b4 = c(NA,
NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1)), .Names = c("id1", "id2", "b1",
"b2", "b3", "b4"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

df
   id1 id2 b1 b2 b3 b4
1    1   a NA  1 NA NA
2    2   b NA NA  1 NA
3    3   c NA NA NA  1
4    4   d  1 NA NA NA
5    4   e  1 NA NA NA
6    4   f  1 NA NA NA
7    4   g  1  1 NA NA
8    4   h  1  1 NA NA
9    4   i  1  1  1  1
10   4   j  1  1  1  1
```

I need to get it into long format, while ONLY keeping values of 1. Of course, I tried using `gather` from `tidyr` and also `melt` from data.table to no avail as the memory requirements of them are explosive. My original data had zeros and ones, but I filled zeroes with NA and hoped `na.rm = TRUE` option will help with memory issue. But, it does not.

With just ones retained and lengthened, my data frame will fit easily in memory I have.

Is there a better way to get at this vs. using the standard methods - reasonable compute as a tradeoff for better memory fit is acceptable.

My desired output is the equivalent of:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% gather(b, value, -id1, -id2, na.rm = TRUE)
   id1 id2  b value
1    4   d b1     1
2    4   e b1     1
3    4   f b1     1
4    4   g b1     1
5    4   h b1     1
6    4   i b1     1
7    4   j b1     1
8    1   a b2     1
9    4   g b2     1
10   4   h b2     1
11   4   i b2     1
12   4   j b2     1
13   2   b b3     1
14   4   i b3     1
15   4   j b3     1
16   3   c b4     1
17   4   i b4     1
18   4   j b4     1

# or
reshape2::melt(df, id=c("id1","id2"), na.rm=TRUE)
# or 
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id=c("id1","id2"), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Currently, the call to `gather` on my full data set gives me this error, which I believe is due to memory issue:

```
Error in .Call("tidyr_melt_dataframe", PACKAGE = "tidyr", data, id_ind,  :
  negative length vectors are not allowed
```

Comment: The filter to value == 1 is redundant in your example. It would be helpful if you had an example that reproduced the error.

Comment: Yeah...I did not clean it up after subbing NA for zeroes. :)

Comment: How sparse is it - perhaps use actual sparse `Matrix`?? If keeping the original zeros... `m = as(as.matrix(d[-(1:2)]), "TsparseMatrix") ; out = data.frame(id1 = d$id1[m@i+1], id2 = d$id2[m@i+1], b = names(d[-(1:2)])[m@j+1], value = m@x)`. Or not using matrices ...`r = which(d[-(1:2)]==1, arr.ind=TRUE) ; out2 = data.frame(id1 = d$id1[r[,"row"]],  id2 = d$id2[r[,"row"]],  b = names(d[-(1:2)])[r[,"col"]])` . no idea if it scales.

Comment: These are some excellent solutions. Unfortunately, my data is too big and fails to create the vector 'r' or sparse matrix 'm'. Looks like I need to do `gather` one column at a time and `rbind` results. I have 306 columns of zeroes/ones and looping + row binding will take time but may overcome memory challenge. Let me try and see.

Comment: That fails too on out of memory. The server has 256GB memory, but apparently, that is not enough on this data. :) Wish there was a more memory efficient solution to sparse situations like mine.

Comment: thats a shame. thought sparse matrix may be a good bet, as really you seem to just need the row and column index of non-zero terms, and if your data is sparse it should be (more) memory efficient.

Comment: last go at creating the indices /: `ro = which(d[-(1:2)]==1) ; co = (ro - 1) %/% nrow(d) + 1 ; ro = (ro - 1)  %% nrow(d) + 1` Out of memory again?

Comment: @user20650 : I guess `d[-(1:2)] == 1` could be the one that runs into memory problems? (btw, it could replaced by `which(d[-(1:2)] == 1, TRUE)`). Probably, collecting the row indices by column could spare the memory needed from the "nrow(d) * length(d)" logical -- `ro = lapply(df[-(1:2)], function(elt) which(as.logical(elt))); co = rep(seq_along(ro), lengths(ro)); ro = unlist(ro, , FALSE)`

Comment: Hi @alexis_laz ; thought that was probably the issue, I considered using lapply / sapply but thought that creating all the logical vectors (even temporarily) in a list would cost more memory (ie I dont understand how R manages the memory of objects)

Comment: @user20650 : I'd guess that, since `lapply` evaluates `which(<logical>)` iteratively, the memory used from a logical vector (created for a column) will be released after being passed to `which` before the next iteration so, I think, storing `length(d)` logical vectors of `length == nrow(d)` could be avoided in this case.